# Ruby- extract a value inside a nested json

Tags: json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to retrieve the thumbnail for a video insdie a json sent by facebook

If I do in ruby

```
address = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/936915709799694/thumbnails?access_token=EAACEdEose0cBAIEEedXcwXMsqusqhdudsqhusdqhsduhdsudshudshudsds'
example = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(address))
```

I get an escaped version of the following json (note that there is only one key data which then is an array of jsons)

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "936918379799427",
      "height": 720,
      "scale": 1,
      "uri": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t15.0-10/27853051_936918406466091_6621898933939470336_n.jpg?oh=1b4afa6cfca7030b98915e12ab85cf70&oe=5B1CFCFA",
      "width": 1280,
      "is_preferred": false
    },
    {
      "id": "936918369799428",
      "height": 720,
      "scale": 1,
      "uri": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t15.0-10/27260162_936918416466090_2202441332260077568_n.jpg?oh=894848d7069f27010c055757e3449ec1&oe=5B228409",
      "width": 1280,
      "is_preferred": false
    },
    {
      "id": "936918376466094",
      "height": 720,
      "scale": 1,
      "uri": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t15.0-10/27415107_936918419799423_2695587454257201152_n.jpg?oh=f1f03e6b754cb9365dd7319d6a72c401&oe=5B1C02A1",
      "width": 1280,
      "is_preferred": false
    },
    {
      "id": "936918373132761",
      "height": 720,
      "scale": 1,
      "uri": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t15.0-10/27410300_936918423132756_1211957161530228736_n.jpg?oh=3c52834d0148e52ec4d6b30df7d18725&oe=5B17CFCA",
      "width": 1280,
      "is_preferred": true
    },
    {
      "id": "936918383132760",
      "height": 720,
      "scale": 1,
      "uri": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t15.0-10/27596995_936918429799422_8351220412767535104_n.jpg?oh=e4bc154cd5a5bfff72934516aeb36c43&oe=5B1841C0",
      "width": 1280,
      "is_preferred": false
    }
  ]
 }
```

I would like to grab the json where is_preferred=true then extract the uri inside this json

so in the above example, the correct json piece would be

```
{
      "id": "936918373132761",
      "height": 720,
      "scale": 1,
      "uri": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t15.0-10/27410300_936918423132756_1211957161530228736_n.jpg?oh=3c52834d0148e52ec4d6b30df7d18725&oe=5B17CFCA",
      "width": 1280,
      "is_preferred": true
    }
```

and the uri to retrieve would be

```
https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t15.0-10/27410300_936918423132756_1211957161530228736_n.jpg?oh=3c52834d0148e52ec4d6b30df7d18725&oe=5B17CFCA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
data = JSON.parse(response_body).fetch('data')
uri_list = data.select { |img| img['is_preferred'] }.map { |img| img['uri'] }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the JSON data and then step through it with an `each do` iterator.

Here is an example of your code for setting up the parsing:

```
require 'json'

address = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/936915709799694/thumbnails?access_token=EAACEdEose0cBAIEEedXcwXMsqusqhdudsqhusdqhsduhdsudshudshudsds'
example = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse( address ))
json_data = JSON.parse(example)
```

From there, you need to pull out just that array from the 'data' hash like so:

```
json_data['data']
```

You can put that resulting array of hashes directly into the `each do` iterator

```
json_data['data'].each do |hash|
    # do something with the individual hash
end
```

Now that you've got your hands on each hash at a time, you just need to check if the has has the value you're looking for:

```
if hash['is_preferred'] == true
    # then yes, this is the hash you are looking for, store it/do something with it
end
```

So, in the end, here it is all tied together:

```
require 'json'

address = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/936915709799694/thumbnails?access_token=EAACEdEose0cBAIEEedXcwXMsqusqhdudsqhusdqhsduhdsudshudshudsds'
example = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse( address ))
json_data = JSON.parse(example)

json_data['data'].each do |hash|
    if hash['is_preferred'] == true
        # then yes, this is the hash you are looking for, store it/do something with it
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks, it worked but panic method is shorter/cleaner

Comment: That's fine. Much of the mentality around Ruby is around readability over efficiency, and I would argue that my final code is far more readable. However, there's nothing to force you from using more efficient code ;)